# Random value being inserted into database when using php

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to insert a phone number into my database. I'm able to connect, and insert all the other data from my form (address, email, ect.) into the database perfectly fine, but when the phone number is inserted it ignores the actually phone number an ONLY inputs this int 2147483647. No matter what phone number I use only those numbers show up in the column within my database. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the part of the php that collects the phone number from the form on my website

```
$Phone1 = $_POST['Phone1'];
```

Here's the html form that gets the phone number

```
<span>
            <input id="element_2_1" name="Phone1" class="element text" size="10" maxlength="10" value="" type="text">
            <label for="element_2_1">(###) ### - ####</label>
</span>
```

here's the SQL Insert Statement

> `` $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO `phpmy1_belairfinishing_com`.`Contact`(`ID`, `FName`, `LName`, `Phone`, `Street`, `City`, `State`, `Country`, `Zipcode`, `Email`, `Message`) VALUES (NULL, '".$FName."', '".$LName."', '".$Phone1."', '".$Street."', '".$City."', '".$State."', '".$Country."', '".$Zipcode."', '".$Email."', '".$Message."')"; ``

Comment: what is the column type for `Phone` ?

Comment: **warnning** your code may be vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: @DanielA.White I've been using $Street = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Street); for all the other data fields but thought this might be causing the problem so I stopped using it for the phone number. Are you saying I should add it back?

Comment: international phone numbers may start with 0.

Comment: show us more code. what is the value of $Phone1. do `echo $Phone1` and you can chenge input type to NUMBER if you don't worry about old browsers. When people aksed you about type oh Phone - they mean - what is the field 'phone' type in your database table phpmy1_belairfinishing_com ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're storing your phone number as an INT, and phone numbers are **NOT** ints. A signed 32bit int has a max value of 2,147,483,648. In phone number terms, that'd be 214-748-3648. If you're inserting a phone number "bigger" than that, e.g. 777-777-7777, well you're getting exactly what you want - the largest possible signed 32bit integer representation of your phone number.

Use a varchar field instead.

Comment: Additionally, a phone number can start with meaningful zeros, and these would be ignored if taken as a number.

Answer (score 2):

the db tries to interpret you phone number as int but the value is larger thax max column int value hence max int

Answer (score 1):

Don't save phonenumber as Int save it as a Varchar

Why should you do this?

As you don't need to calculate with a phonenumber and mostly only show it Varchar is of better use.